# How to use JsonTextReader twice

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am given a stream of json data which contains a field named "type".  This type field describes the type of object that needs to be created at runtime.  It looks like I am unable to use the JsonTextReader twice and I cannot find away to reset the text reader to the beginning.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    JToken token = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);
    var type = (string) token.SelectToken("type");
    var modelType = Type.GetType("Project." + type + ", Project");

    // Fails here
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, modelType);
}
```

I get this error message.
Unexpected token while deserializing object: EndObject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a JsonReader from the JToken.

```
JsonReader reader = token.CreateReader();
```

Comment: That doesn't work when the type you're looking for is in a generic array, like <IEnumerable<ISomething>>

Answer (score 3):

To reset your reader to the begginning, set the Position property of the underlying stream to 0.

```
streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
```

Edit:
While this will reset your underlying stream, the jsonTextReader is **forward-only** by definition, which means its line number and position are readonly. For this to work you would have to reset the streamReader position, then feed it into a **new** JsonTextReader object.

So unfortunately Phil, there is no way to read the JsonTextReader twice since it is forward-only.

Reference:
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm
"Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to serialized Json data."

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work correctly? Both the `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` probably keep internal state that won't be reset by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I cover using the `JsonTextReader` in a memory-efficient format, avoiding the Large Object Heap, etc., [in my blog](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/10/22/ultrafast-json-parsing/), as per James Newton King's recommendations. You can leverage this and the supplied code to read your JSON multiple times without worrying about the underlying implementation of `JsonTextReader`.

Comments and feedback always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing and found that the following works.

1. Set `JsonTextReader.CloseInput = false`
2. Destroy the `JsonTextReader` (by closing the `using` statement)
3. Set `StreamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0`
4. Create a new `JsonTextReader`

It would look something like this:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
{
    Type modelType = null;

    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        jsonTextReader.CloseInput = false;

        JToken token = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);
        string type = (string)token.SelectToken("type");
        modelType = Type.GetType("Project." + type + ", Project");
    }

    streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, modelType);
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't work. Unless you specify the `leaveOpen` parameter in the constructor of `StreamReader`, it will close the underlying stream. If you fixed that, this could work if the code in the question worked, but it doesn't.

Comment: My original post was tested, but incorrectly.  I've updated it.